# Create a folder in MSI using Wix ToolSet Installer

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, wix

I'm trying to create a folder using WixToolSet inside a main folder, but it does not create any folder, all it places is one file in the main folder.

```
<Product Id="*" Name="HdxInstallerApp" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Waters" UpgradeCode="e42c1c6a-57fb-403d-9d7e-25fe2d6ec88d">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="HdxInstallerApp" Level="1">
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
    </Feature>
</Product>

<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
    <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="HdxInstallerApp">
      <Directory Id="client" Name="client"></Directory>
      <Directory Id="webserver" Name="webserver"></Directory>
    </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
    <Component Id="appsettings.Development.json" Guid="3fcaf8c6-1d6e-43ba-8b46-30af729ea751">
      <File Id="appsettings.Development.json" Name="appsettings.Development.json" Source="$(var.ClientProject_TargetDir)appsettings.Development.json" />
    </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

Whats the mistake here or am i missing something?

I saw a tag  but how to place files inside it?

Comment: With that how do I add files in the folder?

Comment: Please check out the docs: https://wixtoolset.org/docs/v3/howtos/general/specifying_source_files You can also specify `Directory` attribute for your components/component groups.